# Selection on ListBox to fill active cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fill the active cell with value from clicked listbox item
This attempt throws an error "Argument not optional" and this is as far as I can go.

```
Sub ListBox13_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim InstrRange As Range
Set InstrRange = Range("A4:A200")
If Not Intersect(Target, InstrRange) Is Nothing Then
    Set InstrRange = Range("A" & Target.Row)
    Range("A" & Target.Row).Select
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It is telling you not optional because This is a listbox change, target is empty. I would normally not use the change event like that, but instead of target, can you try ByVal ActiveCell As Range?

Comment: Sub ListBox13_Change(ByVal ActiveCell As Range)

Dim InstrRange As Range
Set InstrRange = Range("A4:A200")
If Not Intersect(Target, InstrRange) Is Nothing Then
    Set InstrRange = Range("A" & Target.Row)
    Range("A" & Target.Row).Select
End If

End Sub

Comment: Nothing happens either way: ByVal ActiveCell As Range or (ByVal Target As Range. Any idea?